# How to create a new database table whenever user changes options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options

I'am new to wordpress plugin development and I'am stuck in developing menu for my plugin.

By going through documentation and many sites i created following menu. But i want to create a new table in the database specified by user..Is there any action hook to detect whenever user types something and presses save button.

How can i know whenever user changes option..Any action hooks that i can use..
I want to create a new table whenever user changes his options.

[image]

Comment: Why would you possibly need to create a whole new table when a user saves an option?

Comment: I need to store some registration entries.

Comment: I assumed as much, but why do you need to create a whole new table?

Comment: This is a plugin for sending push notifications whenever a new post is published.
In order to store the registration Id's to whom i should send a push notification i need a table which contains all registration Id's